# Hyperledger Fabric: Chaincode container cannot connect to local peer

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, shim

While instantiating a very simple chaincode I get the following error in chaincode container and instantiation fails:

```
2018-04-06 15:29:51.923 UTC [shim] userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 001 Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded
Error starting SimpleAsset chaincode: Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded
```

Which environment variables are determining the connection from chaincode container to the peer? How can I check this further?

Peer Version: 1.0.6 
Orderer Version: 1.0.6

Comment: What type of environment are you using here?

Comment: 2 Peers and 1 Orderer running on separate servers. Peers are dockerized. Running the orderer directly from the binary. I do not see any issue on orderer side.